# Developing WYSIWYG editor - Javascript/HTML5 contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg, contenteditable

code here: http://pastebin.com/pukt7TQv
(html/javascript/css is all inline for simplicity of including complete source)

I can insert tags but not attributes, details in pastebin, but simply put inserting a tag calls a function called insertTag(tag), and inserting an attribute (for example font size="3") calls insertAttr(tag, attr) where tag would be 'font' and attr would be 'size="3"'.  insertTag() uses surroundContents(), but surroundContents() doesn't support attributes, and I can't figure out another way of inserting the tag with attribute.

Feel free to rip this code off for your own purposes too, it's simple and somewhat functional! :D

Comment: Updated and moved to JSFiddle so it's easier to work with. This problem has been solved by applying css styles on creation of the element instead of actual HTML attributes.
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/makr8100/qPdu7/)